# Get fractional part from floating point sum

Tags: floating-point

Say we have the following floating-point sum:

x.a + y.b = z.c

I am interested in obtaining the "real" fractional part of the result of the sum "c" as accurately as possible. It cannot be accurately obtained by using modulo 1 on the sum.

What I have so far is using a step from KahanSum to get the inaccuracy of the sum and then add the inaccurate fractional part of the sum to obtain the accurate fraction (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm)

```
function FractionOfSum(float x, float y)
  var t = x + y
  var c = (t - x) - y
  return c + (t % 1)
```

Same code in C#

```
float FractionOfSum(float x, float y)
{
    float t = x + y;
    float c = (t - x) - y;
    return c + (t % 1);
}
```

However, this will not be as accurate as it could be and for very large numbers whole integers will be lost, so the result will no longer just be the fractional part.

Why not just add "a" and "b" and take the fraction of that? Because c does not equal (a + b) % 1 in certain cases such as -11.8 + 12.4 = 0.6

Edit: For a negative number, the fraction should be negative as well

Comment: Take the *.a* and *.b* parts and order them by magnitude, so that *.a* is not lesser in magnitude than *.b*. Then add them. If the floating-point result is greater than 1, then | *.a* | ≥ ½. Then computing *.a* − 1 in floating-point with round-to-nearest is exact, and *.a* − 1 + *.b* will yield the desired result as closely as the format can represent it. Similarly, if the sum is less than −1, then use *.a* + 1 + *.b*. Otherwise, use *.a* + *.b*.

Comment: Re “Why not just add "a" and "b" and take the fraction of that? Because c does not equal (a + b) % 1 in certain cases such as -11.8 + 12.4 = 0.6”: This is unclear. If you want −11.8 and 12.4 to yield .6, then simply take *.a* and *.b* as the symmetric remainder modulo 1. That is, for −11.8, *.a* would be −.8. If the final result is negative, you can add one, although this may lose accuracy.

Comment: What do you want to return for `fractionOfSum(1-2^-20, 2^-20*(1-2^-20))` (where `^` is power, not xor)? The closest fraction of that would round to `1.0` in single precision.